# How can I replace the stock driver module inside a Linux ISO?

Tags: linux, software-installation, drivers, system-installation, proprietary-drivers

In particular, I want to replace the stock network drivers (r8169) with something else (r8168) in the installation ISO. Is this possible?

Currently, I have to install Ubuntu/Debian/CentOS (same problem with the driver in all distros) first, and then install the correct network driver, add it to the kernel and then blacklist the old one. I would like to avoid this long winded process if possible. Hopefully, there's a way to do this on Windows (Understandably, I don't want to boot into the Linux installation without a working internet connection).

Isn't there a way to do this from within Windows? For example, by opening up the iso files and replacing the stock driver module... Where are the network drivers located within the ISO?

Comment: Don't know how it go in other distrom, but in Debian, missing firmware automatically promt at installing. Just put your firmware in a flash drive and it will get loaded.

Comment: Actually, the firmware isn't missing, so it doesn't get prompted. It just needs to be replaced since the default one has problems. Will it work if I simply place the new firmware within the \pool\restricted directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mount to ISO file to a loopback device and edit the files. Since you are only changing a firmware file you would not need to rebuild the ISO after the change.

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 filename.iso /mnt/iso
```

You only need to rebuild the ISO if you change something in the boot record.

Comment: In addition to this, ensure that you rebuild the initrd image **if the driver you intend to replace** is part of the initial ram disk image.  For CentOS (I'm familiar with that one), this means: 1) install the module, 2) place a file in /etc/depmod.d/*<modname>*.conf, 3) rerun depmod (*depmod -a*), 4) rebuild initrd (*dracut -f*).  That dracut command is applicable for the currently executing kernel only.  Read the man page for its usage for other kernels.

Comment: The new Linux install doesn't have the right driver yet, so I don't want to boot into it and not have an internet connection in case I need to check something online again. Isn't there a way to do this from within Windows? For example, by opening up the iso files and replacing the stock driver module... Where are the network drivers located within the ISO?

Comment: Linux doesn't allow mounting ISO files as read-write - to modify an ISO image you'll need to extract the contents and then rebuild the image using, eg, `myhybrid` or `mkisofs`.

Comment: mjturner, I mount ISO images on my GNU/Linux machines and write to them all of the time. As long as you mount it on a loopback there should be no troubles. Yogesch, if you wanted to do this on Windows you can use an ISO writer to open up the image to edit the files. Most driver firmeware (which is what you normally need to replace/add) will be located in /lib/firmware.

Comment: @elixir Odd, I've never been able to do that (they always mount read-only), nor find any references online to mounting ISO9660 ISO images read/write on a Linux system. See, eg [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/523847/how-to-update-mount-create-iso-image-as-read-write), and [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110749/mounting-iso-image-message-block-device-is-write-protected-mounting-read-only) and the [ISO9660 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660): "ISO 9660 is by design a read-only, pre-mastered file system"